# new directive leads to ng-change firing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm quite new to angular and have the problem, that i want to use a variable for defining the ng-model. This works now, but now i have the problem that the ng-change event fires twice, when using this directive.

I set the priority of the dynamic-model directive to -1, as the ng-change depends on the model of course...

```
...
app.controller('testcontroller', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.model = "dynamicmodel";
})

app.directive('dynamicModel',function($compile){
  directive = {
    priority : -1,
    link:function(scope,element,attr){
      element[0].removeAttribute('dynamic-model');
      element[0].setAttribute('ng-model',scope.$eval(attr.dynamicModel));
      $compile(element[0])(scope);
    }
  }
  return directive;
});
```

And the html

```
<p>[[item.key]] <input type="text" dynamic-model="model" ng-change="update()" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'default blur', debounce:{default:1000, blur:0}}"></p>
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r9t2mjy4/

What can I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: I would consider rewriting this whole thing. The current state it is in is very...very poor. What you are trying to do is something extremely simple, and you have made it extremely complicated. Also remember that you should not be using any type of jquery inside your controllers, or directives for that matter, learn to make use of the element in directives.

Comment: Sorry, but what is so poor about it? I mean theres not really that much code in it...I know i should probably not use jquery, but for just trying it's easier for me...i would remove it later, when the stuff i want to achieve is working....what exactly did i make extremly complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a directive, if you add another directive to an element, make sure it have a lower priority than yours.

Than call $compile passing your current priority:

```
app.directive('dynamicModel',function($compile){
  directive = {
    priority: 2,
    link: function(scope,iElement,iAttrs){
      iElement[0].removeAttribute('dynamic-model');
      iAttrs.$set('ng-model',scope.$eval(attr.dynamicModel));
      $compile(iElement[0])(scope, null, 2);
    }
  }
  return directive;
});
```

Comment: but the priority should be higher (so priority < 0) as ng-change depends on the model

Comment: it's the other way around, the higher the priority number, the sooner it runs.

Comment: are you sure? Because if i set a higher priority i get an error message - Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found! - because the ng-model is not set when the change directive runs

Comment: let me check priority for ngChange.

Comment: I'm sure. ngChange is at priority 0, while ngModel is at 1. I've edit my post to use iAttrs.$set(), have a try. Otherwise, a plunk would help

Comment: but then ng-change does not work - i set up a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/r9t2mjy4/